# MobileWiFi Framework for reading WiFi RSSI iOS 10

Tags: wifi, ios10, rssi

is someone using this API to read the wifi signal strength in rssi, on an iOS 10 device? Is it still possible without a jailbreak, or not? The Infos out there are very rare :/.

Thanks in advance